# NSTableView checkbox value from CoreData in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, nstableview

I have an issue with a in a TableView checkbox not changing its state depending on a coredata record.

I display other information from coreData model perfectly well, but my checkbox in the code does not seem to relate to the checkbox in the NSTableView. There is an enum CellIdentifiers containing column identifier. The function fetchTraceValue retrieve the data from core Data, and that works. the problem is really how to relate to the checkbox in the Cell. My tableView is ViewBased.

This is in tableView function :

```
let checkbox = NSButton() 
var text: NSString = ""
var cellIdentifier: String = ""

if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[0] 
{
let selected:Bool = self.dataHandling.fetchTraceValue(key: "selected", id: row+1, folder: self.currentFolder) as! Bool            
checkbox.intValue = (selected) ? 1: 0)
cellIdentifier = CellIdentifiers.TraceSelCell
}
```

I have found some things here but all of them in Objective-C.

Thanks

Comment: Use Cocoa Bindings. As CoreData is widely based on KVC this is a very efficient solution and you get rid of a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: Thanks for that. I’m struggling a bit with making a managedcontextobject kvc compliant as I don’t have accès to the fike’s owner property to bind it... I don’t know why that is. :)